# VBA column value comparison

Tags: excel, vba, comparison

I have two excel sheets. The first sheet has this data:

```
Column C
--------
101-AA-103  
101-AA-104  
101-AA-105  
101-BB-101
```

The second sheet has this data:

```
Column A
--------
101-AA-100  
101-AA-101  
101-AA-102  
101-AA-103
```

I want to compare column C from the first sheet with column A from the second sheet. For example, value 101-AA-103 from column C on the first sheet needs to be checked against all the rows in column A on the second sheet. If the value is found, it should say "Available"; otherwise, "Not Available". How can I write a VBA function to do this?

Comment: Hey, I've just answered your question, then I had a doubt that your question was written in a wrong way: infact you didn't split rows so I thought it was a single string. Too bad :(

Comment: No it was multiple word. i want to split the exact word and then compare. Column A (1st sheet) --> 009-AB-001-XL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim strToFind As String
Dim res As Range
dim maxrows as Integer

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
maxrows = 500

For i = 1 To maxrows
    strToFind = sh2.Cells(i, "A")
    With sh1
        Set res = .Columns("C").Find(What:=strToFind, After:=.Cells(1, "C"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If res Is Not Nothing Then
          'Do here what you please
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Note that you should calculate maxrows and not use a const integer.

Comment: @user899902: don't take my code as _perfect_, it's just an idea of what you could/should do

Comment: @user899902: take a look at my edited post: this code should work for your needs

Answer (score 0):

You could do this really easily using Vlookup:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Not Available","Available")
```

But since you asked for VBA, here's a function that will do it, utilizing a dictionary object and variant arrays for efficiency and speed.

- Dump Column C and Column A into a variant array
- Make a dictionary of Column A values
- Search through the column C entries to see if they exist in A
- The variable i is the row number as well, so it's rather simple to place text in column D.

```
Sub TestAvailability()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim varrayC As Variant, varrayA As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

lastRow = Sheets(2).range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
varrayA = Sheets(2).range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value

lastRow = Sheets(1).range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
varrayC = Sheets(1).range("C1:C" & lastRow).Value

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To UBound(varrayA, 1)
    dict.Add varrayA(i, 1), 1
Next

For i = 1 To UBound(varrayC, 1)
    If dict.exists(varrayC(i, 1)) = True Then
        Sheets(1).cells(i, 4).Value = "Available"
    Else
        Sheets(1).cells(i, 4).Value = "Not Available"
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Technically you could create a new array of availability and transpose it on column D, but I didn't want to make it overly complicated.